# Why is this php and MySQL not displaying results

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently trying to connect to a database and display the first names of all the students in the table "STUDENTS". I seem to be connecting fine, as my ping() seems to go through fine. I am not receiving an error message of any sort, but my query/displaying the results seems to not be working. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

```
  <?php
    $user = 'root';
    $password = 'root';
    $db = 'gradebook';
    $host = 'localhost';
    $port = 8889;

    $link = mysqli_init();
    $connection = mysqli_real_connect($link, $host, $user, $password, $db, $port)
        or die("Cannot connect to database server.");

    /* check connection */
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    /* check if server is alive */
    if (mysqli_ping($link)) {
        printf ("Our connection is ok!\n </br>");
    } else {
        printf ("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM STUDENTS";

    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($First_name);
    while ($statement->fetch()) {
        print $First_name . '</br>';
    }

    mysqli_close($link);

    ?>
```

Comment: There's no `mysqli_fetch` funciton. It's `fetch()`.

Comment: Even when using fetch() it does not work..

Comment: Do you see `Our connection is ok!`?

Comment: Yes, that appears but nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, start with turning on error reporting.

Then - read mysqli-manuals carefully.

`$link = mysqli_init();` returns object.
`mysqli_real_connect` returns **bool**.

And you're trying to execute `prepare` method on bool variable:

```
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
```

Surely it doesn't work. And if you had error reporting `on` - you would see a relevant error message. So, assuming everything else is fine:

```
$statement = $link->prepare($query);  // NOT $connection
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result($First_name);
while ($statement->fetch()) {
    print $First_name . '</br>';
}
```